# Using Xampp to set server status response code manually

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

How do manually set Xampp's response from a request like a GET or POST to HTTP 1.1 200 OK?

Comment: XAMPP is an installer and launcher for Apache, MySQL, PHP and Perl. XAMPP itself does not respond to requests and does not control how Apache responds to requests. Apache will respond to all properly formed HTTP requests for resources which exist with a 200 status code. How to send a 200 status in some other situation depends on the situation, which you've not shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using `header()`, as in:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
```

Comment: THaank you. Do you know how respond with txt/html?

Comment: As far as I know there is now way to generate a header with just txt or HTML. As @Dan Grossman mentioned, if you just provide a valid page, it should also return 200 OK. Maybe if you explain what you need we could be more helpful.